# Layout Params: What imports do I use?

Tags: android, import, admob, landscape, setcontentview

I'm in a similar situation to this guy:
[Implementing Admob banner when setContentView() is used for the Surfaceview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573930/implementing-admob-banner-when-setcontentview-is-used-for-the-surfaceview)

My "sGame" creates a landscape view game that I want with an admob ad put on top.

I think the answer will work, but I'm not sure which LayoutParams to import for the "layout.setLayoutParams".

When I hit Alt+Enter on the LayoutParams, I get the following options:

```
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.GalleryLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams;
//... quite a few more options
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different layout managers use different layout parameters. It's very obvious: `RelativeLayout` uses `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`, `LinearLayout` uses `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` etc.

**That means, you need to use** `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`:

```
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;
```

Because in the link you mentioned, the answer tells you to use `RelativeLayout`.

And now, let me give you some extra information. What if you use the wrong params? An `InvalidCastException` is thrown. When you encounter that exception, you would probably know what is wrong. You use the wrong type of Params. And Android is trying to cast that type of Params to the correct type!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of `layout`.

From the link, it's a `RelativeLayout`, so you need import `android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`.