# Interstitial Ad with setContentView

Tags: android, admob, interstitial, setcontentview

I'm trying to add an interstitial to my app that uses setContentView. I've already got a "listener" implemented that properly calls whenever an ad is needed. You can abbreviate your answer by calling this function "Listener"{...} and assume that everything within the brackets will occur whenever the app signals for an ad. The following answer has a good method for Banner ads.

[Implementing Admob banner when setContentView() is used for the Surfaceview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573930/implementing-admob-banner-when-setcontentview-is-used-for-the-surfaceview)

My question is, in this scenario, how should I implement an interstitial?

My code is basically the answer from the link, plus this:

```
...    
        setContentView(layout);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        listener= new PropertyChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
                if (event.getPropertyName()=="sharing1") {
                    caring();
                    game.dead=false;
                    game.sharing1=false;
                }
                if(event.getPropertyName()=="dead")
                {
                //Make an interstitial ad here
                }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you're asking but unlike banner ads, an interstitial ad is a pop up which displays independently of the underlying activity's content view.

You can call your function after calling #setContentView(). Perhaps you should post some code so we know what specific problems you're facing

**UPDATE:**
You can preload and show it only when needed, in this case when the player "dies". This would reduce latency. After each display of an ad, you must reload the ad so they get shown upon subsequent calls. Also, use a handler if your listener would be invoked in a non-UI thread. Here's a solution:

```
...   



  InterstitialAd interstitial; 
        setContentView(layout);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        InterstitialAd interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId("your-ad-unit");
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        // Preload your interstitial to avoid load time delays 
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
        listener= new PropertyChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
                if (event.getPropertyName()=="sharing1") {
                    caring();
                    game.dead=false;
                    game.sharing1=false;
                }
                if(event.getPropertyName()=="dead")
                {
                //Make an interstitial ad here
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        if (interstitial != null && interstitial.isLoaded()){
             interstitial.show();
             //reload ad 
             interstitial.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());             
             }  
        }
    });
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: The code is essentially exactly the link's. The only difference is that I have a "listener" that can call an ad multiple times.

Comment: @ArriFerrari Alright. I've modified my answer. Hope it helps

Comment: Well, the problem I'm having is that by using setContentView(); I seem to be blocking the ad.

Comment: Blocking the ad?  You mean no ads show? Check the messages posted to your stack trace log when the game is running. Maybe that would help

Comment: For whatever reason, it didn't work in the emulator, but I created an apk and it works.